# What is the best practice when unit testing methods that have assertions instead of exceptions?

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit, assertions

Let's say you have a public method like this

```
public Sprite spriteAt(int x, int y) 
{
    assert withinBorders(x, y) : "PRE: x and y should be inside the borders";

    return tileAt(x, y).topSprite();
}
```

Versus

```
public Sprite spriteAt(int x, int y)
{
    if (!withinBorders(x, y)) throw new InvalidArgumentException();

    return tileAt(x, y).topSprite();
}
```

In the bottom case, I would usually have a unit test cases that checks if an exception is thrown when invalid value for x and/or y are given like:

```
@Test(expected = InvalidArgumentException.class)
public void SpriteAt_InvalidX_ThrowsInvalidArgumentException()
{
    sut.spriteAt(-100, 0);
}
```

This test case is to ensure that the argument validating logic is implemented in the method.

However, for the assertion method at the top, I am not sure what I am supposed to do. The assertions are not production code and I think this means I don't have to test the assertions.

On the other hand, I think unit tests should notify the developer by failing when there is a change of logic in a method. If I do not write a test case for checking if there is an assertion that checks invalid arguments (just like how I do for exception method), then I may not realize I have made a mistake when I accidentally remove the assertion line of code.

Therefore, what I want to do is to check whether assertion is in place if junit is ran with assertion enabled and don't do anything when assertion is not enabled. Below code will contain pseudocode.

```
@Test
public void SpriteAt_InvalidX_AssertionThrowsException()
{
    if (assertion is enabled)
    {
        try
        {
             sut.spriteAt(-100, 0);
             fail();    
        }
        catch (AssertionFailureException e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

So back to my point. I want to know whether unit tests are supposed to test assertions. If so, am I going in the right direction? If not, how do you prevent from accidentally removing assertion code without unit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.

In my opinion if you *want to test* the case where `x`or `y`are not within range explicitly than you should throw the `IllegalArgumentException` and not use `assert`. On the other hand you have no method comment that *tells* the caller of this method that `x`or `y`must be within a range. So if you see it from the callers perspective you have no right to assert this at all. :-p

I would use `assert` for checking pre conditions I have no unit tests for. But on the other hand you simply should have a unit test for that example.

At the end of the day `assert` throws a `RuntimeException` as well and - as you told - only during development time when a compiler flag is that. So why not simply use the `IllegalArgumentException` which seems perfect for that case. And please give the caller of the method the hint in which case it is thrown with the `@throws` comment.

My conclusion: `assert` is rather useless as long as you have good unit test coverage. It's **only good for manual testing during development** to check up pre conditions where you don't want or can write explicit unit tests for.

Answer (score 0):

You can always test the `assert` functionality if you turn it on by using `-ea` java command argument.

`assert` throws `java.lang.AssertionError`.

**Unit tests should test the behavior, not the implementation**. So if the asert behavior is not explicitly defined in the contract (JavaDoc) you should not test it.

**`assert` is pretty useless and is almost never used in real systems.**

Comment: Can you elaborate your last statement? I also have the feeling that assertions aren't too important (aside from unit testing), but I'm still a junior.